# Cut off block based on certain strings in a file

Tags: batch-file

I have a task to cut off the block starting from certain string in the middle of a file and then to save this upper part of the file into a new file.

```bat
;---- Some text A
aaaaaaa1111
……..
aaaaaaa2222
;-----Some text B
bbbbbbbbb1111
………….. 
bbbbbbbbb2222
```

Now I am looking for a batch file to cut off the part starting from:

```bat
;-----Some text B
```

So after cut, the new file looks like:

```bat
;---- Some text A
aaaaaaa1111
……..
aaaaaaa2222
```

All the part starting from:

```bat
;-----Some text B
bbbbbbbbb1111
………….. 
bbbbbbbbb2222
```

has been cut off.

I tried to use the Function from DOStip then call that function as below:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
REM.-- Prepare the Command Processor
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo.Extracting hello world block into "Load_SDK.M83" file
call:extractFromFile ";---- Some text A" ";---- Some text B">"Load_SDK.M83"
:extractFromFile - extract lines from a file between begin and end mark
:: - %~1: begin mark, use '...$' mark to allow variable substitution
:: - %~2: optional end mark, default is end of file
:: - %~3: optional source file, default is THIS file
SETLOCAL
set bmk=;---- Some text A
set emk=;---- Some text B
set src=C:\Files\Load_all.M83
set /a b=-1
set /a e=-1
if "%src%"=="" set src=%~f0& ::- if no source file then assume THIS file
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('"findstr /n /b /c:"%bmk%" "%~f0""') do (
    set b=%%a
    set bmk=%%b
)
if /i %b%==-1 echo.ERROR: begin mark '%bmk%' not found in '%src%'&GOTO:EOF
if "%emk%"=="" (set /a e=2000000000) ELSE (
    for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('"findstr /n /b /c:"%emk%" "%~f0""') do (
        if /i %b% LSS %%a if /i !e!==-1 set e=%%a& rem -- find only the first one after b
    )
)
if /i %e%==-1 echo.ERROR: end mark '%emk%' missing in '%src%'&GOTO:EOF
if /i %b% GEQ %e% echo.ERROR: end mark '%emk%' detected before begin mark '%bmk%' in '%src%'&GOTO:EOF
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%a in ('"findstr /v /n /b /c:"#$*ReturnAll*$#" "%src%""') do (
    if /i %b% LSS %%a if /i %%a LSS %e% (
        if "%bmk:~-1%"=="$" (
            rem --sustitution variables within %%b
            call echo.%%b
        ) ELSE (
            rem --no variable substitution
            echo.%%b
        )
    )
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Just so everyone knows, the OP has got extensive help on this question already at [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8909)

Comment: Without us having to go off site, can you please provide a genuine example of the file content, what you require as an end result based upon it, the script you've used in your attempts to achieve it, and how that script fails to perform the task it was written to perform.

Comment: I note that the content of your file does not match the provided code. We need either genuine content with code written for it, or generic content, _(which means that solutions may not work with the actual file content)_, and code written to match. The code you've added as an edit does not represent the task as you've explained it in your question, which seems to require only a single `For` loop with an `If` and a `GoTo`. Please try harder to produce a question which doesn't require a whole lot more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment, a one line single `For` loop with an `If` and a `GoTo` seems to perform the task as shown in your question:

```bat
@(For /F UseBackQDelims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ("source.txt") Do @If /I Not "%%A"==";-----Some text B" (Set /P "=%%A"<Nul&Echo=) Else GoTo :EOF)>"result.txt"
```